# Host's File Permissions in Solaris

Tags: linux, permissions, hosts, solaris

On a Solaris 10 server I am trying to edit the hosts file but it's preventing me from doing so saying it's read only. I am logged in as the root user.

When I `ls -l` on the `/etc` directory I see the following;

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  12 Apr 25  2008 hosts -> ./inet/hosts
```

I've read that the `l` at the beginning of the permissions means that this file is linked to another - presumably the `/inet/hosts`. However I can't see any files in this location.

Any idea how I can edit the hosts file, and how it ever got the `lrwxrwxrwx` permissions in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try editing `/etc/inet/hosts`.

in ls -l results there is a leading dot

```
hosts -> ./inet/hosts
```

which mean you start from `/etc`